# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Constructed Languages Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **September 20th** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on September 20th, users can [nominate themselves](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On September 27th, if there are **two or more** candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than two candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on October 5th (or October 12th, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 4):

The official call for nominations will come out soon, and I want to encourage active users of this site to nominate themselves. Moderation of conlang is currently a lightweight task and a good opportunity to become a moderator without prior moderation experience.